# App Inventor 2 - How to make a sprite walk to the position of touch?

Tags: android, app-inventor

I want the sprite to walk towards the position of touch. To be more precise I want it to move like the main sumo in this game: https://youtu.be/Gj5CwgFUbI0?t=56s

The buttons provide pixel by pixel movement but I've to keep pressing them again and again to reach a point.
The Canvas event directly puts the sprite to the position touched.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkVyf.jpg]

Comment: Your question has been answered in the [App Inventor forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/ElORiH4qOBg/M-a6fKBUCQAJ) by Ghica. In case you still have questions, then follow up there. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered by Ghica on [Mit App Inventor forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/ElORiH4qOBg/M-a6fKBUCQAJ) and I just made a few edits. I used blank png 10*10 pixel as a Target Sprite.

[.aia file](https://groups.google.com/group/mitappinventortest/attach/9f8fc2f4834c7/billy_copy2.aia?part=0.1&authuser=0)
[image: Here are the blocks]

Answer (score 0):

The logic should be like this, but i can't make it works, it's always freeze when the button touched.

[image]

My guess is because MIT App inventor doesn't support multi threading. Sorry that was as far as i can help.

Comment: [Why is a wait procedure generally a bad idea?](http://josmasflores.blogspot.com/2013/02/a-single-thread-of-execution-in-app.html), [The model of event processing in App Inventor](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/m8i32I2m200/Am3VYo3DTIUJ) by Lyn, [Please Wait method](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/PhX0rRpvH-Q/fcUacQziCwAJ) by Scott

Comment: got sorted,Thanks!

Comment: I will keep this answer to make sure that other users with this same approach will aware if it is not possible and not a good idea. You can look at Yashw's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/40345698/3940133 instead